# A cohomology associated to a symplectic manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Let  $(M,\omega)$  be  a  symplectic  manifold.

Let  $$\Omega_{\omega}^k(M)=\{\alpha \in \Omega^{k}(M)\mid \alpha \wedge \omega \;\;\text{is  an  exact  form}\}$$

Then  we  have a chain  comlex$$\ldots \to \Omega_{\omega}^{k-1}(M)\to \Omega_{\omega}^k(M)\to \Omega_{\omega}^{k+1}(M)\ldots$$  with the  standard  differential operator  $d$.  so  we obtain  a  cohomology $H_{\omega}^k$.

Does  this  cohomology  depend  on  choosing the  symplectic  structure  $\omega$? Does this  cohomology contains  some  information about the  symplectic  manifold? Is there a  trivial  description for  this  cohomology?

**Note:** In this way one can  associate a  cohomology to  an  arbitrary  manifold by consideration of  the  cotangent  bundle as a symplectice manifold.

Comment: The only thing that you use to obtain the chain complex is the fact that $\mathrm d \omega = 0$, which means that you could construct such a complex for every closed form $\omega$, not necessarily nondegenerate, not necessarily skew-symmetric, not necessarily of degree $2$. Hard to believe that such a theory could encode useful information about the underlying symplectic manifold.

Comment: @AlexM.  Yes of  course. very interesting  comment. "hard to  believe that such a  theory..". Yes but the  first step is  that one provide two different   symplectic $\omega$  whose  corresponding  cohomologies  are  non  isomorphic. On the  other  hand,  however  we  did  not  use  non degenerat... etc. but  one  can not 
 absolutly  says that this  cohomology  has  nothing to  do with  symplectic properties of  M.

Comment: @AlexM.  BTW  what  do  you mean  by  "  not  necessarily  skew  symmetric"?

Comment: I mean that you don't use anywhere the assumption that $\omega$ is skew-symmetric, so you could as well drop it completely (along with the assumption of non-degeneracy and degree $2$, that aren't used in your construction either).

Comment: @AlexM.  skew symmetric is  included in the  definition of  differential  forms, if  by  skew  symmetry  you  mean $\omega(v,w)=-\omega(w,v)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, you are right concerning skew-symmetry: I had in mind "skew-symmetric tensor" because I was thinking about Poisson manifolds.

Comment: I think this group is infinite. Take a manifold M with $\omega$ not exact and let $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\omega$ is also not exact. Then $df$ defines a nontrivial element in your group.

Comment: @AaronBergman  I  am  thinking of  this  cohomology  as  a  vector  space so  is  it  infinite  dimensional.? Lets  consider  a  compact  surface  then for  every  f, g there  is  a  c  with $\int_M f-cg=0$.

Comment: If I read you right, you are observing that, for a 2-manifold, we can choose a $g$ s.t. $dg = df$ and $g\omega$ is exact. But I don’t think this works in higher dimensions. If $g\omega$ is exact, then $dg\,\omega = df\,\omega$ is necessarily zero, and it’s easy to choose $f$ such that $f\omega$ isn’t closed, so no such $g$ can exist.  And, yes, I did mean infinite dimensional.

Comment: @AaronBergman  No  I  mean that  $(g-f)\omega$  is  exact, by the  converse of  Stocks theorem.

Comment: So we  di  not get  a  infinite  dimensional  cohomology

Comment: Same thing. My $g$ is your $g-f$.

Comment: The map $i$ from simply forgetting the exactness condition: $\Omega_\omega^\bullet \to \Omega^\bullet$ might be useful.

Comment: @AaronBergman  Yes  you are  right. In my previous  comment I was considering "surface"  not  higher  dimensional case.

Comment: @AaronBergman  Thanks  again for your  comment. I realize that the  cohomology  is  infinite  dimensional(at least in order 1)